# Map a Azure Fileshare to Azure Runbook local drive to use as temporary storage

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, runbook

I am trying to access an AzureStorage to utilize it in an Azure- Powershell-Runbook.
I need to accomplish that to save a SharePoint-Sitetemplate to that location.
Things I've tried was using:

```
$StorageAccountKey = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'StorageKey'
$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'spotemplatestore' -StorageAccountKey 
$StorageAccountKey
$container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name 'spotemplatestore' -Context $Context
```

But I don't know how to access that locally.
Using New-PSDrive is not an option as it does not work with Azure Powershell Runbook
Trying to use c:\ directly doesn't work either as the runbook does not have writing permissions ont c:\temp directly.

Answer (score 0):

As Runbooks in Azure Automation run on the Azure cloud platform, ***they do not have access to resources in other clouds or your local system.***

In order to access resources in local system, make use of **[Hybrid Runbook Worker feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker)** of Azure Automation.

Please **note** that,

> **PowerShell support to install the extension-based Hybrid Runbook Worker is not supported at this time.**

To install that feature, make use of ***Azure portal***, by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker#hybrid-runbook-worker-installation).

For more information, please **refer** the below links:

[powershell - Azure Runbook - Get a file from Azure File System Storage - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531989/azure-runbook-get-a-file-from-azure-file-system-storage)

[powershell - Not able to access Azure FileShare Storage container from Azure Automation Runbook - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926695/not-able-to-access-azure-fileshare-storage-container-from-azure-automation-runbo)

Comment: my Q for this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73886790/1747983