# PS Azure automation runbook ; How to Mount Azure File Share?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-automation, azure-files

Trying to mount Azure FS from Powershell runbook in Azure Automation.
Via username and key

```ps
$UserName = "localhost\trex4xfs"
$Key = "Zav---mykey-----1Tdw=="
$RemotePath = "\\myshare.file.core.windows.net\mainfs"
$MapDrive = "z:"

Get-Command -Name *SmbMapping* | ft

[securestring]$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $key -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $pass

new-psdrive -name T -PsProvider FileSystem -root $RemotePath -credential $credential
Get-PSDrive | ft

echo "--------now import smb"
Import-Module smbshare
echo "--------now smb"
New-SmbMapping -LocalPath $MapDrive -RemotePath $RemotePath -UserName $UserName -Password $Key
```

Above works great on "plain Powershell on Windows"

Tried

- Runbook with 5.1 and 7.1 PS version
- new-psdrive (error: `This function is not supported on this system` )
- New-SmbMapping (error 7.1:  `The 'New-SmbMapping' command was found in the module 'SmbShare', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module SmbShare'`
- New-SmbMapping (error 5.1: `Cannot connect to CIM server. The specified service does not exist as an installed service.` )
- Import-Module smbshare (error  `Failed to generate proxies for remote module 'smbshare'. Cannot overwrite the item C:\Users\Client\Temp\tmp_5t22mi1k.oh0\remoteIpMoProxy_smbshare_2.0.0.0_localhost_f29e4e95-e8cf-4256-a4db-fc9381c6563c.format.ps1xml with itself.`)
- New-CimSession (error: `The specified service does not exist as an installed service.`)

Seem to be related to `New-CimSession` not available on Azure Automation runbook

other questions related to this:

- [Azure Runbook - Get a file from Azure File System Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50531989/1747983)
- [Not able to access Azure FileShare Storage container from Azure Automation Runbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63926695/1747983)
- [Map a Azure Fileshare to Azure Runbook local drive to use as temporary storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72049057/1747983)

Answer (score 0):

One of the related question which you have shared already provides the answer (i.e., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72049057/map-a-azure-fileshare-to-azure-runbook-local-drive-to-use-as-temporary-storage) one) which basically says to use hybrid runbook worker in your use case scenario.